# $k$-dimensional manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $k<m$ are non-dense and have measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be a smooth (connected) $k$-dimensional manifold with $k<m$. Is it then true that $V$ is non-dense and has measure zero?

It seems a pretty straightforward question. I had no success in finding a suitable theorem/lemma.

Comment: Assuming a decent embedding (e.g., that it's actually a submanifold), use Sard's theorem, the constant rank theorem, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Just look at Sard's Theorem and take $f = \iota$ which is the inclusion.